# Oracle DB - Table join issue when no matching data exists

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have Oracle DB and two tables as follows

**Vaccine_Trns**

```
ID  | Vac_Code | Patient | TxnDate
--------------------------------------
V01 | SER520   | test1   | 2020-12-07
V02 | SER519   | test2   | 2020-12-07
V03 | SER520   | test3   | 2020-12-07
V04 | SER523   | test4   | 2020-12-07
V05 | N/A      | test5   | 2020-12-07
```

**Vaccine_Msr**

```
ID     | Desc |
------------------
SER519 | VacDesc01
SER520 | VacDesc02
SER523 | VacDesc03
```

I know that when I join the two tables by `Vac_Code` in **Vaccine_Trns** and `ID` in **Vaccine_Msr**, I loose V05 row in **Vaccine_Trns**, but is there a way to fetch results in this way below?

without V05 its a simple join but I am confused of what to do here.

Thank you very much in advance.

**Expected Results >>**

```
Patient | Desc      |  TxnDate
--------------------------------
test1   | VacDesc02 | 2020-12-07
test2   | VacDesc01 | 2020-12-07
test3   | VacDesc02 | 2020-12-07
test4   | VacDesc03 | 2020-12-07
test5   | null      | 2020-12-07
```

Comment: Hint: `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`:

```
select vt.patient, vm.desc, vt.txndate
from Vaccine_Trns vt left join
     Vaccine_Msr vm
     on vt.Vac_Code = vm.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEFT JOIN`

```
select t.Patient, m.desc, t.txndate
  from Vaccine_Trns t left join Vaccine_msr m
    on t.Vac_Code  = msr.id
```